# How can I insert the current logged in user in a database using ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to insert the current logged in user in a database. I had an idea of making a hidden input text field in the view, taking its value, and inputting it in the database using the asp-for. But it doesn't seem to work. Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong and if you have any other suggestion on how to fix this in any other way, feel free to tell me.
Thank you in advance <3
This is the **view** code (P.S I took out some code of the view, I feel as though it is unnecessary for the questions purpose):

```
<form asp-action="Create">
<div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
</div>
        <input type="hidden" value="@UserManager.GetUserName(User)" asp-for="User" readonly>
</form>
```

This is the **controller** code:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("OrderId,Model,Color,Size,Seizure,HatchTrap,User")] ShutterOrders order)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _context.Add(order);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Create));
    }    
    return View(order);   
}
```

Comment: Have you read through the documentation? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio. If you're using ASP.NET Core Identity and setting it up correctly, you should be able to get the user name of the logged in user in your controller by `User.Identity.Name`.

Comment: @DavidLiang Yes I know that, but how would I add it using the _context from the database. Should I assign User.Identity.Name to a var and then add it somehow or?

Comment: you can use `User.Identity.Name` in your controller, and then save it normally same as you do with a `string`

Comment: @B.S I changed the User to a string instead of an object from the Identity class in the model and it worked. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you just want to save in your table `order`, supposing that `user` exist and is a string in your table, just do in your controller:

```
// create a new entry
order myOrder = new order();

// assign values
myOrder.User = User.Identity.Name;
// save other things if necessary...

// add the new data in your table
_context.order.Add(myOrder);

// save 
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```